# Xcode - EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when concatenting a large string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'm getting a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when concatenting a large string.

I've read from a feed and to create my webview I build up my string like:

```
NSString *pageData = @"<h1>header</h1>";

pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingFormat@"<p>"];
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingFormat@"self.bodyText"];
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingFormat@"</p>"];
etc
```

The problem I've got is self.bodytext is 21,089 characters with spaces when I do a count on word. 
Is there a better method for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Check your sample code for cut-n-paste problems.  Are you missing a colon after "stringByAppendingFormat" or is that really your code?  Also, in the second append are you really putting "self.bodyText" inside of quotes (i.e. as an NSString) or are you actually doing "stringByAppendingFormat: self.bodyText", (with out the @ and the quotes)?

Answer (score 6):

You would definitely want to use [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for something like this:

```
NSMutableString * pageData = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

[pageData appendFormat:@"<h1>header</h1>"];
[pageData appendFormat:@"<p>"];
...
```

`NSMutableString` is designed for this kind of sequential concatenation, where the basic NSString class is really not meant to be used in this manner. Your original code would actually allocate a new NSString every time you called `stringByAppendFormat:`, and then procede to copy into it all of the thousands of characters you had already appended. This could easily result in an out of memory error, since the size of the temporary strings would be growing exponentially as you add more and more calls.

Using NSMutableString will not re-copy all of the string data when you call `appendFormat:`, since the mutable string maintains an internal buffer and simply tacks new strings on to the end of it. Depending on the size of your string, you may want to reserve a huge chunk of memory ahead of time (use a meaningful number for the `...WithCapacity:` argument). But there is no need to go that route unless you actually run into performance issues.

Comment: Since neither the example in the question, nor the sample code in the answer are actually using formats, you should probably use appendString: for NSMutableString ( see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-appendString_) or stringByAppendingString: for NSString instances (see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:)

Comment: @Jason Jenkins: Absolutely true. I stuck with the `appendFormat:` method because I *assume* that the OP will be inserting some dynamic data into the string eventually. Otherwise, he may as well type everything out in a text file and avoid the mutable string alltogether `:)`

Comment: What if the self.bodyText happened to include a substring that looked like a format specification (e.g. a '%@')?  At runtime, with no arguments given, could that result in the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS the questioner is getting?

Comment: Yes, it definitely could. I think you may be right about his intent for "self.bodyText" Why not post it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your sample code:

1. You should be using a NSMutableString to build up an output string by appending multiple parts.  NSString is an immutable  class which means that each time you call `stringByAppendingFormat:` you are incurring the overhead of creating an additional new NSString object which will need to be collected and released by the autorelease pool.

   `NSMutableString * pageData = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];`
2. You should use `appendString:` on your `NSMutableString` to append content, instead of `stringByAppendingFormat:` or `appendFormat:`.  The format methods are intended for creating new strings based on a format specifier which includes special fields as placeholders. See [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) for more details.  When you're using `stringByAppendingFormat:` with just a literal string like your code has, you are incurring the overhead of parsing the string for the non-existant placeholders, and more importantly, if the string happens to have a placeholder (or something that looks like one) in it, you'll end up with the `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` crash that you are getting. Most likely this happening when your bodyText is appended.  Thus if you simply want to append a '

   ' to your `NSMutableString` do something like this:

   `[pageData appendString:@"<p>"];`
3. If you want to append the contents of the `self.bodyText` property to the string, you shouldn't put the name of the property inside of a string literal (i.e. @"self.bodyText" is the literal string "self.bodyText", not the contents of the property.  Try:

   `[pageData appendString:self.bodyText];`

As an example, you could actually combine all three lines of your sample code by using a format specification:

```
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingFormat:@"<p>%@</p>", self.bodyText];
```

In the format specification `%@` is a placeholder that means insert the result of sending the  `description` or `descriptionWithLocale:` message to the object.  For an `NSString` this is simply the contents of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the length of the string is really a problem. A 50,000-character string is only about 100 KB. But you want to be very careful about using format strings. If your string contains something that looks like a formatting specifier, there had better be a corresponding argument or you'll get garbage if you're lucky and a crash if you're not. I suspect this is the error, since there is no other obvious problem from your description. Be careful about what you put in there, and avoid ever putting dynamic text in a format string — just put a `%@` in the format string and pass the dynamic text as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use appendString: instead of appendFormat: when dealing with arbitrary strings.

```
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingString:@"<p>"];
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingString:@"self.bodyText"];
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingString:@"</p>"];
```

or do not use an arbitrary string as the format:

```
pageData = [pageData stringByAppendingFormat:@"<p>%@</p>" , @"self.bodyText"];
```

If you are building the string up in pieces, use NSMutableString instead of several stringBy calls.

Remember that % is a special character for formatted strings and for url escapes, so if bodyText contains a url it could easily cause a crash.